# Testing something completely different I noticed buggy bahaviour with tensile scrolling a List

Tags: codenameone

I was trying whether it was a good idea to use shape clipping in a list renderer - and found some very old bugs still exist.

It's just a List in a Form with BorderLayout as CENTER component.

My custom ListCellRenderer has a style with a bgPainter which applies clipping with a round edged shape created using a GeneralPath.

Scrolling the List beyound it's start paints over the forms toolbar.
[image: cell renderer background paints on form caption]

Tapping before the tensile scrolling moves the list to the bottom of the form - which I reported a long time ago - see https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone/issues/1365
[image: list sits at bottom after tap while scrolling]

Dragging beyond start of the list releasing the pointer above the caption of the form apparently does not cause a pointerUp - see:
[image: one still selected after pointer up]

You can test all of this using a simple List which is smaller than the form and which has a renderer that paints its background.

Comment: This tensile scrolling - will it ever work well enough to be used?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are calling setClip(Shape) without regard to what the current clip is.  When you call setClip() it will replace any existing clip, it won't form the intersection.  You have to form the intersection yourself.  I plan to add a `clipShape(Shape)` method which is analogous to `clipRect()` and will set the clip to the intersection of the current clip and the shape you provide.  But until that happens, you'll have to form the intersection yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue in shape clipping and the `clipRect`method.

Regardless of this issue I would not do that.

Shape clipping is very expensive in terms of performance and produces an aliased result by definition (as opposed to the more refined anti-aliased result). You would end up having slower code that doesn't look as refined as other approaches to do the same thing e.g. image borders, fill etc.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a list where the entries backgrounds are blurred above a background image. That might work well having the background image and a blurred image resembling a blurred version of the same image painted as background of the list entries. And shape clipping because of the round edges. That should look quite cool.

Comment: You can use the Gaussian blur effect to do the image https://www.codenameone.com/blog/toastbar-gaussian-blur.html since it's done once the performance penalty is paid in advance and not with every frame like the shape clipping which will slow down performance. Will you will the content of the shape with some color/design? If so you can create that color/design as an image and use that as a background/border which will be far more efficient

Comment: Well, yes that is what I wanted to do. I'll use shape clipping only if it is fast enough.

Comment: But the List behaviour is still buggy. In my opinion the List component is not useable. At least it is not up to my standards.

Comment: We haven't recommended the usage of List for the past two years since the introduction of infinite scroll. Very few of our samples use it. I don't think it's buggy as much as it is "nuanced" which might matter very little semantically with the exception that bugs are fixable and nuanced means you have to build very gently around a complex implementation. We use InfiniteScrollAdapter and InfiniteScrollContainer which are both more performant and easier to use/customize.

Comment: There is the same "nuance" using InfiniteScrollAdapter when the list is shorter than the client area - see issue 1365.
I call it a bug.

Comment: That's something different and has nothing to do with list. That is why you need to file different questions for different issues as you will get answers for other questions. I noticed that you have an issue about that, it relates to pointer released not firing for some edge cases and has nothing to do with the Component level API but rather the low level implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We were talking at cross here. Please ignore the clipping.

There are bugs in the tensile scrolling.

The bugs show in all list implementations and in scrollable containers.

Scrollable containers behave in ugly ways when tensile scrolling is interrupted by tapping while the scrolling is still in progress and even worse when the client area is shorter than the container the content jumps to the end of the container and remains there until dragging anew.
Also when tapping a component in a scrollable container and tensile scrolling is still in progress the content just snaps and the wrong component reacts.

Please do something about it.

Comment: I raised two issues regearding tensile scrolling https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1735 and https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1736

This tensile scrolling thing is not anywhere like the native IOS rubberband scrolling - but it really should be. As is is it cannot be used because it would affect user experience too much.

Comment: You may want to refine the question then.  "Scrolling the List beyound it's start paints over the forms toolbar. " implies that at least part of your question was about the clipping.